# How to change the domain extension on the Android Keyboard

Tags: android, email, keyboard, dns, android-edittext

Is it possible to change the domain extension (.com) on the Android Keyboard when you have an EditText field that is specified to be android:inputType="textEmailAddress"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, there's been another discussion about that, basically, it states that there's no direct influence of the field on what extension the on-screen keyboard shows.

[android:inputType="textEmailAddress" - '@' key and a '.com' key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440327/androidinputtype-textemailaddress-key-and-a-com-key)