# How can I add ".com" button to Android keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android:inputType=“textEmailAddress” - '@' key and a '.com' key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440327/androidinputtype-textemailaddress-key-and-a-com-key)

In my project I have an EditText in which user should enter his E-mail. How can I add ".com" button to Android Keyboard?

This is my code:

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/etEmail"
android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_span="4"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
/>
```

==========>
**Update:**

I had this problem in my Emulator (and still have actually). but when i checked on real device, Samsung Galaxy S2, I saw ".com" button. Therefore, on real device there is no problem. But my suggestion for emulator users is go to Settings/Language & Keyboard and then clear the tick of Chines Language and Japanese IME. So, you can see "@" in keyboard (but still there is no ".com" button in AVD 2.2).

Comment: Given the number of different keyboards available for Android devices, the fact that they're their own packages I seriously doubt this is in the least bit feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `android:inputType` should be set to `textEmailAddress` only - specially if this is a field for email. But this option will not work for some devices - SE xperia, for example, does not provide any special keyboard for email input. For other devices it should work.