# Email keyboard for edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

The following Code doesn't seem to work,I want the email keyboard with `@` and `.com` to get displayed for the edit text.

`emailEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440327/androidinputtype-textemailaddress-key-and-a-com-key

Comment: Have you given `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` to your `EditText`'s xml part.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Well I found the solution which is to use

`emailEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);`

Answer (score 91):

Add this to your layout:

`android:inputType="textEmailAddress"`

Comment: That works if you can set it in your layout.  But if you need to *programatically* change the keyboard to this type (i.e. with a toggle-button), SK's answer below is the solution.

Comment: @JosephK what is the reason for dynamically changing inputType for email EditText? :)

Comment: I had a client request we put a button in to toggle the keyboard from number-pad to email-entry - specific type of number-pad and specific type of alpha (with the @ sign).

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin way:

```
email_field.valueEditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```