# how i change my keypad for type mail-id?

Tags: android

I have an EditText box in my android app, and when I click on it to input something, the default input languange is in normal keypad. Can I change it to edit for email-id?

i want @ and .com in my keyboard while entering mail-id .

when i try to use maildId.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
 it show error Fatal exception .

Comment: set input type email

Comment: add `android:inputType` property in xml file

Comment: emaileditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

Comment: this is also works android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

Comment: I wonder if you even tried to google before to post on SO

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) link for different input types..

Comment: i tried android:inputType also . its not coming

Comment: I got it . thanks for the comments :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email keyboard for edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204120/email-keyboard-for-edit-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use input type as:

```
            <EditText

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
              />
```