# TextCapCharacters Issue in Wildfire S

Tags: android, textinput

i am having an issue with TextCapCharacter in MDPI device "WildFire S"
i have 2 edit text Field 
Name and Email Id 
in Name  i m using

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameTV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/input_field_profile"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
    android:paddingRight="5dp">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

and in Email ID

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailTV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/input_field_profile"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" />
```

i m having issue that textCapCharacter properties is Working fine on Name Field but when i shift to Email ID Field it Still keeps input type captextcharacter 
but this thing working Perfectly fine on 
 Samsung Google Nexus 
 Samsung Galaxy Note II
 Samsung Galaxy SII
so need help on this issue 
Thank You Regards Usman Arshad Kurd

Comment: So.. What exactly is the problem? Is your keyboard is not appearing according to the `inputType` or it is not verifying the text as email in field?

Comment: in wildfire S my keyboard is not showing according to my InputType

Comment: Well then have a  look at my ans...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link below might give you a clear indication, why is it so on some devices:

[android:inputType="textEmailAddress" - '@' key and a '.com' key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440327/androidinputtype-textemailaddress-key-and-a-com-key)

This explains all about it.